# Is there a browser extension to change the time returned by the Date object?

Tags: javascript, datetime, browser-extension

Are there browser extension to change what's returned by JavaScript's Date object without changing your system clock?

This is something that comes up a lot when you're creating brochure-ware. You often want to show the visitor a particular promotion or creative treatment based on the current date. If you're using the visitor's system clock, testing becomes annoying because you have to change your own system clock, which of course messes up your calendar reminders and god knows what else.

Comment: is it an option for you to call a new, custom function instead of messing with the native Date object? I realize that you would potentially have to update a lot of code to point to this new date object..

Comment: That would be my fallback. I'd like to have a repeatable way to test this kind of behavior without adding code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not advisable in production, in a dev environment, you could do the following:

```
var dateYouWant = 1363798981693; 
Date.prototype.getTime = function() { 
    return dateYouWant;
};
console.log( (new Date).getTime() );
```

Essentially, overriding the `Date()` function to return whatever time you specify.

Comment: I think the best answer might be something like this wrapped as a bookmarklet that the tester can use to set the time in their browser.

Answer (score 0):

Since you replied to my comment saying that you would call a wrapper function as a fallback, let me provide that function. I hate modifying native objects, so I would go this route:

[Here is a jsfiddle to play with.](http://jsfiddle.net/lbstr/79hUn/)

```
function getScaledDate(offset){
    // if you don't pass in an offset
    if (offset === undefined) {
        // check to see if there is a global one defined
        if (typeof GLOBAL_DATE_OFFSET !== "undefined") {
            offset = GLOBAL_DATE_OFFSET;
        }
        // otherwise, don't add an offset
        else {
            offset = 0;
        }
    }

    return new Date(+new Date + offset);
}

// USAGE:
var now = getScaledDate();
var oneHourFromNow = getScaledDate(1000 * 60 * 60); 
var oneHourAgo = getScaledDate(-1000 * 60 * 60); 

// GLOBAL OFFSET USAGE:
window.GLOBAL_DATE_OFFSET = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 7; // scale everything 7 hours foward
var scaledDate = getScaledDate(); // will use global offset
```